# Why isn't Task.WhenAll working?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task

Here's some code I'm working with, that fires of three tasks. My Stop is called, and from the output, it looks as though the tasks finish *after* Stop returns, which isn't what I'd expect.

This is Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5.1

I tried the same using AutoResetEvent which worked as expected.

Here's the output from this:

```
Three tasks without auto reset
Starting...
FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
Running...
FIRST
FIRST
FIRST
SECOND
FIRST
FIRST
THIRD
...
SECOND
FIRST
Stopping...
THIRD
All done!
First done
Second done
Third done
```

What I'd expect to see is:

```
First done
Second done
Third done
All done!
```

Here's the code (I even added locking around the Console output, but it made no difference):

```
public class ThreeTasksWithoutAutoResetEvent
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellation;

    private Task[] tasks;

    private object obj = new object();

    public ThreeTasksWithoutAutoResetEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Three tasks without auto reset");

        cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

        tasks = new Task[3];

        Message("Starting...");

        Start();

        Message("Running...");

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Message("Stopping...");

        Stop();

        Message("All done!");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        tasks[0] = this.First(cancellation.Token);
        tasks[1] = this.Second(cancellation.Token);
        tasks[2] = this.Third(cancellation.Token);
    }

    private async void Stop()
    {
        cancellation.Cancel();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task First(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Message("FIRST");
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                Message("First done");
            }, token);
    }

    private async Task Second(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Message("SECOND");
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }

                Message("Second done");
            }, token);
    }

    private async Task Third(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Message("THIRD");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }

                Message("Third done");
            }, token);
    }

    private void Message(string message)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` *is* working - the task it returns terminates only when all other tasks terminate. Your code though *doesn't* await on it though - `Stop()` returns `async void` which means it's fire-and-forget: the method returns immediately and there's no way to `await` for it to end

Comment: You're right, it's my misunderstanding of what's happening in Stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not waiting for `Stop` method to finish. You can't wait for an async void method. You need return a Task, so that the caller can wait/await for it to complete.

```
private Task Stop()
{
    cancellation.Cancel();

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Then you can call `Stop().Wait();` instead of `Stop`. That will wait for `WhenAll` to complete.

Comment: What about removing the async and await - that still doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @imekon not sure I understand your question. You have to call `Stop().Wait();` not just `Stop();`

Comment: Stop().Wait() doesn't compile.

Comment: @imekon Read my answer fully. You need to modify the Stop method as I shown above

Comment: My bad. Your way works, the order makes sense. But why doesn't removing async/await achieve the same result? As in: private void Stop() { cancellation.Cancel(); Task.WhenAll(tasks); }

Comment: Just read the intellisense help, I need Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();

Comment: `WhenAll` just returns a Task which will complete when all of the tasks complete. It doesn't waits. If you want to wait right away, you can use `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` and that will work.